# Xamarin.Android autofill framework hint constant for Date of Birth

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, autofill

I am optimizing my app for Android Autofill framework as per details given [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/text/autofill-optimize).

But I have observed that the there are lots of additional [Autofill Hint Constants](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/autofill/HintConstants#constants_1) which are not available in Xamarin Android.

Is there any way that I can make use of this Hint Constants in Xamarin.

I have specific requirement of `AUTOFILL_HINT_BIRTH_DATE_FULL` and `AUTOFILL_HINT_BIRTH_DATE_FULL` constants in my app.

I am using latest version(28.0.0.3) of all `Xamarin.Android.Support` packages.

Answer (score 1):

In Xamarin.Forms, you could use Autofill Effect.

Autofill effect: create a AutofillEffect.cs

```
public class AutofillEffect : RoutingEffect
{
    public AutofillEffect() : base("YourProjectName." + nameof(AutofillEffect)) 
    {
    }
}
```

The AutofillContentType is an enumerable type that lists all the supported autofill entries.

```
 public enum AutofillHintType
{
    EmailAddress,
    Name,
    Phone,  
}
```

Add an AttachedProperty that can be used by the view.

```
using FormsElement = Xamarin.Forms.Entry;

public static class Entry
{
    const string EffectName = "YourProjectName." + nameof(AutofillEffect);

    public static readonly BindableProperty AutofillHintProperty =
        BindableProperty.CreateAttached(nameof(AutofillHint),
                                        typeof(AutofillHintType),
                                        typeof(Entry),
                                        AutofillHintType.None,
                                        propertyChanged: OnAutofillHintPropertyChanged);

    public static AutofillHintType GetAutofillHint(BindableObject element)
    {
        return (AutofillHintType)element.GetValue(AutofillHintProperty);
    }

    public static void SetAutofillHint(BindableObject element, AutofillHintType value)
    {
        element.SetValue(AutofillHintProperty, value);
    }

    private static void OnAutofillHintPropertyChanged(BindableObject element, object oldValue, object newValue)
    {
        if ((AutofillHintType)newValue != AutofillHintType.None)
        {
            AttachEffect(element as FormsElement);
        }
        else
        {
            DetachEffect(element as FormsElement);
        }
    }

    private static void AttachEffect(FormsElement element)
    {
        IElementController controller = element;
        if (controller == null || controller.EffectIsAttached(EffectName))
        {
            return;
        }
        element.Effects.Add(Effect.Resolve(EffectName));
    }

    private static void DetachEffect(FormsElement element)
    {
        IElementController controller = element;
        if (controller == null || !controller.EffectIsAttached(EffectName))
        {
            return;
        }

        var toRemove = element.Effects.FirstOrDefault(e => e.ResolveId == Effect.Resolve(EffectName).ResolveId);
        if (toRemove != null)
        {
            element.Effects.Remove(toRemove);
        }
    }

    public static AutofillHintType AutofillHint(this IPlatformElementConfiguration<Android, FormsElement> config)
    {
        return GetAutofillHint(config.Element);
    }

    public static IPlatformElementConfiguration<Android, FormsElement> SetAutofillHint(this IPlatformElementConfiguration<Android, FormsElement> config, AutofillHintType value)
    {
        SetAutofillHint(config.Element, value);
        return config;
    }
}
}
```

Android effect implementation:

```
[assembly: ResolutionGroupName("YourProjctName")]
[assembly: ExportEffect(typeof(YourProjctName.Droid.AutofillEffect), "AutofillEffect")]
namespace YourProjctName.Droid
{
   public class AutofillEffect : PlatformEffect
  {

    protected override void OnAttached()
    {
        try
        {
            if (!IsSupported())
                return;

            var control = Control as Android.Widget.EditText;

            var hint = GetAndroidAutofillHint();
            control.ImportantForAutofill = Android.Views.ImportantForAutofill.Yes;
            control.SetAutofillHints(hint);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Cannot set property on attached control. Error: {0}", ex.Message);
        }
    }

    protected override void OnDetached()
    {
        if (!IsSupported())
            return;

        Control.SetAutofillHints(string.Empty);

        Control.ImportantForAutofill = Android.Views.ImportantForAutofill.Auto;
    }

    private bool IsSupported()
    {
        return Element as Entry != null && 
               Android.OS.Build.VERSION.SdkInt >= Android.OS.BuildVersionCodes.O;
    }

    private string GetAndroidAutofillHint()
    {
        var hint = ((Entry)Element).OnThisPlatform().AutofillHint();
        var constantValue = GetEnumDescription(hint);
        return constantValue;
    }

    private static string GetEnumDescription(Enum value)
    {
        FieldInfo fi = value.GetType().GetField(value.ToString());

        DescriptionAttribute[] attributes =
            (DescriptionAttribute[])fi.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DescriptionAttribute), false);

        return attributes != null && attributes.Length > 0 ? attributes[0].Description : value.ToString();
    }

}
}
```

Usage:

XAML:

```
   <Entry HorizontalOptions="Fill"
           Placeholder="Your name"
           Keyboard="Text"
           android:Entry.AutofillHint="Name">
```

Code-behind:

```
  PhoneEntry.On<Android>().SetAutofillHint(AutofillHintType.Phone);
```

Screenshot:

[image]

If you want to use this autofill, you need to save some information. In the screenshot, i used the data by Google Autofill.

[image]